# Error trying to retrieve RTSP Stream from IP Camera (invalid data found when processing input)

Tags: streaming, ip-camera, rtsp, chinese

i'm struggling trying to get FFMPEG working with a Chinese IP CAMERA (Brand: Victure, Model: PC730).

I've been able to obtain and decode RTSP stream from this camera (url like rtsp://user:passw@IP:554/ - no other subpaths needed). 
Different softwares are able to decode this streams for example VLC and ONVIF device manager, but i want to set up transcoding within my Raspberry using FFMPEG as i successfully got working it with all my other cameras.

I've also tried to force UDP or TCP transport with no success.
Below some logs:

```
root@AlRaspiCG:~# ffmpeg -loglevel debug -i rtsp://admin:*****@192.168.199.83:554
ffmpeg version 3.2.14-1~deb9u1+rpt1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --arch=armhf --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'rtsp://admin:*****@192.168.199.83:554'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url rtsp://admin:*****@192.168.199.83:554.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: rtsp://admin:*****@192.168.199.83:554.
[tcp @ 0x6733f0] No default whitelist set
[rtsp @ 0x6715b0] SDP:
v=0
o=- -1946251731 -1946251731 IN IP4 192.168.199.83
t=0 0
c=IN IP4 192.168.199.83
a=packetization-supported:Puwell
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
a=control:trackID=0
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=framerate:0S
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=640028; packetization-mode=1; sprop-parameter-sets=Z2QAKKw7UDwBE/LCAAADAAIAAAMAUQg=,aO484QBCQgCEhARMUhuTxXyfk/k/J8nm5MkkLCJCkJyeT6/J/X5PrycmpMA=
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 8
a=control:trackID=1
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

[rtsp @ 0x6715b0] video codec set to: h264
[rtsp @ 0x6715b0] RTP Profile IDC: 64 Profile IOP: 0 Level: 28
[rtsp @ 0x6715b0] RTP Packetization Mode: 1
[rtsp @ 0x6715b0] Extradata set to 0x671c00 (size: 75)
[rtsp @ 0x6715b0] audio codec set to: pcm_alaw
[rtsp @ 0x6715b0] audio samplerate set to: 8000
[rtsp @ 0x6715b0] audio channels set to: 1
[rtp @ 0x6735a0] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 0x673510] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 0x673510] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[udp @ 0x685e70] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 0x685e70] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
rtsp://admin:*****@192.168.199.83:554: Invalid data found when processing input
```

on picture below, information from VLC player while streaming this RTSP
[stream info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtIJG.jpg)

my questions are:

- how can i better troubleshoot what is the issue preventing FFMPEG to correctly decode this RTSP stream?
- how to fix or find a workaroud? my first aim is to let this camera work inside Shinobi NVR on RASPI as i need to add just this camera to complete my setup.

Answer (score 0):

i found a kind of workaround using VLC.

basically VLC opens corrupted RTSP stream and transcode it to a new RTSP stream.
below command I used:

> cvlc -vvv rtsp://admin:#####@192.168.#.#:554/realmonitor --sout "#rtp{dst=192.168.#.#,port=1234,sdp=rtsp://192.168.#.#:16983/cam3.sdp}"
> it's running thanks to a systemd service into Raspberry Pi 4.

However this solution is neither elegant nor stable, however working everywhere. Stream is often laggy but it's the best I could.

Any furher improvement is welcome.

PS: same apply to a second Victure camera. So not a single model issue (or maybe a precise choice to break RTSP streams..)